# Chaincode PutState() and GetState() values do not match when used with RSA encryption

Tags: rsa, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, chaincode

The following piece of code returns "does not match!" error:

```
pub, priv := GenerateKeyPair(2048)
ct1 := EncryptWithPublicKey([]byte("abc"), pub)
err := stub.PutState("ct", ct1)
ct2 := stub.GetState("ct")
if string(ct1[:]) != string(ct2[:]) {
    return shim.Error("does not match!") //error returned
}
pt := DecryptWithPrivateKey(ct2, priv)
```

RSA library used: https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/3ea9286bd1d3c2a985b67cac4ba2130a

If the string comparison part is commented out, then the decryption function returns the error "crypto/rsa decryption error".

The following code works perfectly:

```
pub, priv := GenerateKeyPair(2048)
ct := EncryptWithPublicKey([]byte("abc"), pub)
pt := DecryptWithPrivateKey(ct, priv)
```

Answer (score 2):

The way that Fabric transactions work mean that you cannot read (GetState) a value from the state database that was written (PutState) during your transaction.  The read (GetState) will always return the value before the transaction started.

The following links on [Transaction Flow](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/txflow.html?highlight=transaction%20flow) and the [sequence diagram](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arch-deep-dive.html#swimlane) will give you more background on transactions if you need it.

Comment: Actually, I initially, found the error when the encryption and PutState was part of one transaction and GetState and subsequent decryption was part of another transaction. It returned "crypto/rsa decryption error". While trying to solve the issue, I ended up merging the functions! I will edit the question to revert back to my original issue. Thank you.